# picture, figure is shifting

Tags: floats

When I add the picture, the word and pdf is the full page and the Latex moves to the right of the page. How can I solve this problem?

this is my work. this is my work and pdf link: *https://we.tl/t-cgDSwDuu8H*

I couldn't stop the pictures from sliding right. What should I do to make the image look like the original PDF file? If I reduce the scale of the picture is centered but this time it becomes very small.

Is a situation caused by page margins?

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper]{article} \usepackage{color} %\usepackage[turkish]{babel} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{tabularx} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{graphicx} %\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{renkbir}{RGB}{0,32,96}

\begin{tabular}{ m{8,5cm} m{6cm} } \Large{\textbf{MsdasdasdN }} \large{\textbf{\textcolor{renkbir}{Firma Adı }}} &\small {Uçak Mühendisi \newline T.C No: asd \newline asd \newline asd \newline asd} \end{tabular} \ %Uçak mühendisi Tc No kısımını sağa yaslamak istedim fakat yapamadım.

\begin{center} \large{\textbf{\textcolor{renkbir}{KİŞİSEL BİLGİLER}}} \end{center}

\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ l l r } Ad & Mehm & \multirow{9}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{2.pdf}} \ Soyad & asdasd \ Doğum Tarihi & sanane (23 Yaşında) \ Adres & asd \ Telefon & asd \ Mail & asd \ Sigara Kullanımı & Hayır \ Ehliyet & B \ Askerlik & Tecilli (31.12.2020) \ \end{tabular}
\end{center}

%\vspace{1cm} Burası boşluk bırakma komutu.

\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ m{4cm} m{6cm} m{5cm} } \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large{\textbf{\textcolor{renkbir}{EĞİTİMLER}}}} \ \hline \multirow{2}{}{Üniversite(YL)} & asd \newline Makine Mühendisliği
\newline Özel Öğrenci / Türkçe
\newline Durumu : Devam ediyor & \multirow{2}{}{Eylül 2018 / } \ \hline \multirow{2}{}{Üniversite} & asd \newline Uçak ve Uzay Bilimleri Fakültesi
\newline Uçak asd
\newline Örgün Öğretim / İngilizce
\newline Durumu : Mezun & \multirow{1}{}{Ekim 2013 / Haziran 2018} \ \hline \multirow{1}{}{Lise} & asd \newline Anadolu Lisesi (100 / 90,02) & \multirow{1}{}{Ekim 2013 / Haziran 2018}
\ \end{tabular} \end{center}

\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ m{3cm} m{4cm} m{4cm} m{4cm} } \multicolumn{4}{c}{\large{\textbf{\textcolor{renkbir}{YABANCI DİLLER}}}} \ \hline \textbf{İngilizce} &\textbf{Okuma:} İyi &\textbf{Yazma:} İyi &\textbf{Konuşma:} Orta \ \end{tabular} \end{center}

\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ m{5cm} m{5cm} m{5cm} } \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large{\textbf{\textcolor{renkbir}{BİLGİSAYAR BİLGİLERİ}}}} \ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Donanım - Ofis Programları} % donann ofis koyu yazmak istedim yapamadım. \
Ms Excel & Çok İyi & +5 Yıl \
MS Word & Çok İyi & +5 Yıl \ Ms Powerpoint & Çok İyi & +5 Yıl
\ \hline \multicolumn{3}{l}{Yazılım Geliştirme} % donann ofis koyu yazmak istedim yapamadım. \ Office & Orta & 2-3 Yıl \
Matlab & Orta & 2-3 Yıl \ Phyton & Orta & 0-1 Yıl \
Fortran & Başlangıç & 0-1 Yıl \
C++ & Başlangıç & 0-1 Yıl \
Ansys & Başlangıç & 0-1 Yıl \ Miktex & Başlangıç & 0-1 Yıl \ \hline \multicolumn{3}{l}{Bilgisayar Destekli Tasarım} % donann ofis koyu yazmak istedim yapamadım. \ SolidWorks & Orta & 2-3 Yıl \ AutoCAD & Orta & 0-1 Yıl \
\end{tabular} \end{center}

\begin{figure} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.pdf} \end{figure}

\begin{figure} \includegraphics[scale=1]{2.pdf} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Latex SS is here: https://i.hizliresim.com/oXgzGm.jpg PDF SS is here: https://i.hizliresim.com/DYMkLv.jpg

Comment: (1) wecome, (2) please show your work, we cannot say much from just images. (3) You might want to use the `pdfpages` package and its `\includepdf{file.pdf}`, it will include one or more pages from a PDF af full page images ignoring document margins.

Comment: LaTex SS mean is, LaTex Screen Shot.

Comment: Don't use `scale`, but `width=\textwidth`.

Comment: Please do not use so cryptic short cuts like SS, specially ther is a very bad meaning existing ...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
 \caption{What happens when image width fit in margins}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{example-image}
 \caption{When image width is too big, it shifts to right}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
 \makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=1.2]{example-image}}
 \caption{If image width is too big, one can fudge it}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]