# figurei picture is shifting

Tags: floats, diagrams

When I add the picture, the word and pdf is the full page and the Latex moves to the right of the page.How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{8.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Latex SS is here: https://i.hizliresim.com/oXgzGm.jpg
PDF SS is here: https://i.hizliresim.com/DYMkLv.jpg

Comment: allways forbidden access ...

Comment: try `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{8.pdf}`

Comment: Please do not ask questions twice https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464297/picture-figure-is-shifting !!